# Set gradient background color to the entire Side-menu

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic3

I have created `Ionic 3` `side menu` project. Now I need to Set gradient background color to the entire Side-menu.It seems straightforward task.But it is not working.Any idea, please?

*app.html*

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-content class="background-gradient">
    <ion-list no-lines>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" class="border-none" outline>
          <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" item-left></ion-icon> {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: string }>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage, icon: 'game-controller-b' },
      { title: 'Activity', component: '', icon: 'browsers' },
      { title: 'Contacts', component: '', icon: 'play' },
      { title: 'Add Project', component: '', icon: 'settings' },
      { title: 'Settings', component: '', icon: 'settings' }
    ];

  }
```

*app.scss*

```
.background-gradient {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-55deg, #50a2a7 35%, #e9b44c 100%);
}

.border-none {
    border: none;
   }
```

It looks like this now:

[image]

**Q:** Can you tell me how to add `gradient background color` to the `menu items` too? i.e. entire `side menu`. I have tried many ways.But no luck yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding a transparent background for the menu items solves this:

```
.border-none{
   border: none;
   background: transparent;
}
```